# Display IP addresses on world map from command line

Tags: macos, dictionary, terminal

Is there a way or an application that I can input data (a csv file) to from command line, and also call the app from command line to dispaly those IP addresses on a world map? I have about 700 addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description what I have here is a tool to display a world map on command line and point the location of ip address on it. Enjoy.
https://github.com/nogizhopaboroda/iponmap